# SQL "NOT LIKE" reduce as many NOT LIKE as you can in a single line

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query where I ask it to bring me information except for a specific one.

Is there a way to reduce the number of NOT LIKE and include it all in the same pattern?

PD: I'm using Redshift AWS.

```
SELECT  distinct action_url 
from event_public
WHERE action_url like '%int/about/%/offices%' 
and action_url not LIKE '%russia%'
and action_url not LIKE '%japan%' 
and action_url not LIKE '%brazil%' 
and action_url not LIKE '%china%' 
and action_url not LIKE '%singapore%' 
and action_url not LIKE '%nigeria%' 
and action_url not LIKE '%algeria%'
and event_action ='Pageview'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use `REGEXP`

```
SELECT  distinct action_url
from event_public 
WHERE action_url like '%int/about/%/offices%'
and action_url not REGEXP 'russia|japan|brazil|china|singapore|nigeria|algeria'
and event_action ='Pageview' ;
```

Edit: For heavy duty matching, don’t use REGEXP() if LIKE can do the job. In particular if a lot of rows can be ruled out by virtue of the first characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "~" POSIX regexp operator.

But the resulting regular expression would be complex and eat up lots of cpu.
See [redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html)

You are probably better of with the simpler but verbose list of likes.

Comment: I agree with what you say. Thank you